# Can colonies become their own countries?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am playing as England, and I have conquered all of the British isles, and I even own the Netherlands and Belgium. I also have a small foothold in France by holding Calais and Picardie. Once I gained all this land, it was about 1510, and I decided to start colonizing. I swept through Greenland, Newfoundland, the thirteen colonies, and all of Hispaniola. In a war with Portugal and Castille, I gained the rest of the Caribbean islands, and I am in 2nd place.

The year is 1574, and I am wondering if any of my colonies can eventually become their own colonies and attempt to gain independence. If they can, should I be worried about it?

Answer (score 4):

You are quite right that they may. Colonial nations might receive cores in the colonies by event, and they may rebel in an attempt to gain independence. They could become quite powerful and sweep through the colonies if not controlled, so keep some forces overseas to keep them in check.

In North America, there are Quebec, Canada, USA, Louisiana and Haiti; in South America  Brasil, UPCA (i.e. Guatemala), Chile, Colombia, La Plata (Argentina), Mexico, Paraguay, Peru, Venezuela.

It's not likely that all of them will appear, but if you control the region for an extended length of time, some probably will.

Apart from that, in the upcoming DLC [Conquest of Paradise](http://eu4wiki.com/Conquest_of_Paradise) (expected mid Jan 2014), larger colonies might become semi-independent from their metropolis and eventually rebel and become separate.

Links:

- [North America at EU4wiki](http://eu4wiki.com/North_america)